# React Native SVG circular animation progress with Circle

Tags: react-native, animation, svg

I am fairly new to React Native programming, I've some experience in Web Development but not so much in animation. So I'm struggling to make a circular progress animation with a line ( **AnimatedPath** ) and a circle ( **AnimatedCircle** ). 
This is my render :

```
<Svg height={size} width={size} style={timerProgressStyle.container}>
<G rotation={rotation} originX={size/2} originY={size/2}>
    <Path d={backgroundPath} stroke={'#fff'} strokeWidth={width} strokeLinecap={lineCap} fill='transparent'/>
    <AnimatedPath d={background} ref={ref=> this.animatedPath = ref} stroke={this.props.strokeColor} strokeWidth={width} strokeLinecap={lineCap} fill='transparent'/>
    <AnimatedCircle ref={ref=> this.animatedCircle = ref} cx={0} cy={size/2} r="10" stroke="white" strokeWidth="0" fill={this.props.strokeColor}/>
</G>
```

and this is my animation function:

```
      startAnimation() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.fill,
        {
            toValue: this.props.higherBound,
            duration: this.props.higherBound * 1000,
            easing: Easing.linear(),
            useNativeDriver: true
        }
    ).start();

    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cx, {toValue: this.state.size, duration: this.props.higherBound * 500, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        ),
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cx, {toValue: 0, duration: this.props.higherBound * 500, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        )
    ]).start();

    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cy, {toValue: 0 , duration: this.props.higherBound * 250, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        ),
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cy, {toValue: this.state.size / 2, duration: this.props.higherBound * 250, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        ),
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cy, {toValue: this.state.size, duration: this.props.higherBound * 250, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        ),
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.cy, {toValue: this.state.size / 2, duration: this.props.higherBound * 250, easing: Easing.linear(), useNativeDriver: true}
        ),
    ]).start()
  }
```

I explain a it a bit: **this.state.fill** refers to the fill of the AnimatedPath, **this.state.cx and cy** refers to the position of the AnimatedCircle. **this.props.higherBound** refers to the number of secs of the duration, **size** is the size of the View of the SVG. The path goes smoothly but I cannot make my AnimatedCircle follow the path as his positions follows straight lines.
I am no expert of animations nor React Native, if you guys could help it would be really good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module like [react-native-progress-circle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress-circle).